# Recursive descent parser from BNF grammar in java

Tags: java, parsing, calculator, recursive-descent

I need to make a recursive descent parser that follows the grammar

```
<program> → <statements>
<statements>→ <statement> | <statement><semi_colon><statements>
<statement> → <ident><assignment_op><expression>
<expression> → <term><term_tail>
<term_tail> → <add_op><term><term_tail> | ε
<term> → <factor> <factor_tail>
<factor_tail> → <mult_op><factor><factor_tail> | ε
<factor> → <left_paren><expression><right_paren> | <ident> | <const>
<const> → any decimal numbers
<ident> → any names conforming to C identifier rules
<assignment_op> → :=
<semi_colon> → ;
<add_operator> → + | -
<mult_operator> → * | /
<left_paren> → (
<right_paren> →)
```

I have made a lexer that tokenizes input into token type, token string, and token value.

```
public Token(int type, String token_string, Object value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.token_string = token_string;
        this.value = value;
    }
public class TokenType {
    public static final int NUMBER=1;
    public static final int LEFT_PAR=2;
    public static final int RIGHT_PAR=3;
    public static final int PLUS=4;
    public static final int MINUS=5;
    public static final int STAR=6;
    public static final int SLASH=7;
    public static final int IDENT=8;
    public static final int ASSIGN=9;
    public static final int SEMI_COLON=10;
    
}
```

I am supposed to parse inputs like

operator1 := 200 + 100 *(100 - 200);

operator2 := operator1 + 300
and return the operator's values

However, I am not sure how I could make the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add `END_OF_TOKEN` to `TokenType`.

```
public class TokenType {
    public static final int NUMBER = 1;
    .....
    public static final int END_OF_TOKEN = 11;
}
```

You define a `Tokenizer` class. It returns a `Token` object by calling `get()`. For simplicity here it returns the `Token` passed to the constructor.

```
public class Tokenizer {
    Token[] tokens;
    int index = 0;

    Tokenizer(Token... tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }

    public Token get() {
        if (index < tokens.length)
            return tokens[index++];
        else
            return new Token(TokenType.END_OF_TOKEN, "End of token", null);
    }
}
```

You define a `Parser`.

```
public class Parser {
    Tokenizer tokenizer;
    Token token;
    Map<String, Double> variables = new HashMap<>();

    Parser(Tokenizer tokenizer) {
        this.tokenizer = tokenizer;
    }

    double factor() {
        if (token.type == TokenType.LEFT_PAR) {
            token = tokenizer.get();
            double e = expression();
            if (token.type != TokenType.RIGHT_PAR)
                throw new RuntimeException("')' expected");
            token = tokenizer.get();
            return e;
        } else if (token.type == TokenType.IDENT) {
            String name = token.token_string;
            token = tokenizer.get();
            if (!variables.containsKey(name))
                throw new RuntimeException("variable '" + name + "' undefined");
            return variables.get(name);
        } else if (token.type == TokenType.NUMBER) {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(token.token_string);
            token = tokenizer.get();
            return value;
        } else
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown token '" + token.token_string + "'");
    }

    double term() {
        double value = factor();
        while (true) {
            if (token.type == TokenType.STAR) {
                token = tokenizer.get();
                value *= factor();
            } else if (token.type == TokenType.SLASH) {
                token = tokenizer.get();
                value /= factor();
            } else
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    double expression() {
        double value = term();
        while (true) {
            if (token.type == TokenType.PLUS) {
                token = tokenizer.get();
                value += term();
            } else if (token.type == TokenType.MINUS) {
                token = tokenizer.get();
                value -= term();
            } else
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    void statement() {
        if (token.type != TokenType.IDENT)
            throw new RuntimeException("identifier expected");
        String name = token.token_string;
        token = tokenizer.get();
        if (token.type != TokenType.ASSIGN)
            throw new RuntimeException("':=' expected");
        token = tokenizer.get();
        double value = expression();
        variables.put(name, value);
    }

    void statements() {
        while (true) {
            statement();
            if (token.type != TokenType.SEMI_COLON)
                break;
            token = tokenizer.get();
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Double> parse() {
        token = tokenizer.get();
        statements();
        if (token.type != TokenType.END_OF_TOKEN)
            throw new RuntimeException("extra token '" + token.token_string + "'");
        return variables;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testParser() {
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(
        new Token(TokenType.IDENT, "operator1", null),
        new Token(TokenType.ASSIGN, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, "200", null),
        new Token(TokenType.PLUS, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, "100", null),
        new Token(TokenType.STAR, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.LEFT_PAR, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, "100", null),
        new Token(TokenType.MINUS, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, "200", null),
        new Token(TokenType.RIGHT_PAR, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.SEMI_COLON, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.IDENT, "operator2", null),
        new Token(TokenType.ASSIGN, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.IDENT, "operator1", null),
        new Token(TokenType.PLUS, null, null),
        new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, "300", null));
    Parser parser = new Parser(tokenizer);
    Map<String, Double> variables = parser.parse();
    System.out.println(variables);
}
```

output:

```
{operator2=-9500.0, operator1=-9800.0}
```